# HTML - How to add a search feature to a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to use a select box in HTML with a dropdown containing many names that the user can type in to search for a name. I do not want the user to add anything that doesn't already exist in the list, just select from the list, but instead of scrolling through 1000's of names be able to search.

Here is what I have so far, it works great but would ideally like the first entry to be a searchable input field that autocompletes based on what is in the list:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('current')}}" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to make this draft pick?')">
    <label for="golferDraft">Golfer to Draft:</label>
        <select name="golfer" style="width: 150px;">
        {% for g in golferList %}
             <option value={{g.dg_id}}>{{g.player_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
<button type="submit">Submit Pick</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown component doesnt have searchable feature. You'll need create searchable dropdown component by combining `input` and `divs` using Javascript.

Consider the dropdown in Tenor, 
https://tenor.com/

They have used combination of `div`, `anchor`,`span` and `input` to achieve the necessary result using JS.

[image]